# How do I know the value type of a Field or the return of a property is actually a Structure

Tags: .net, vb.net, system.reflection

I provide the following snippet illustrates the problem I am having.

```
            For Each mInf As System.Reflection.MemberInfo In ObjA.GetType.GetMembers(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public Or System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance)
                Dim Val_A As Object = ObjA.GetType.GetField(mInf.Name).GetValue(ObjA)
                Dim Val_B As Object = ObjB.GetType.GetField(mInf.Name).GetValue(ObjB)
                If Val_A <> Val_B Then
                    'Do Stuff
                End If
            Next
```

If the value in the field is a user defined structure I get an error when doing Val_A <> Val_B. Also I would need to handle the structure separately. How can I identify that Val_A or Val_B is a Structure?

Comment: Why do you care about knowing? They both act as an object for you to use. Changing from one to another can be as easy as changing the declaration.

Comment: This snipet just demonstrates what the problem I was having is. The code is far more complicated and Object A can be anything. The intent is to audit the objects for differences without knowing what the object really are. I just need to go over each field, each property etc.  iterate trough every collection and go over each value inside the structures if present, etc. and compare and spit out a tree like map of what changed, without knowing what the object structure is. So I need to know what it is I have inside Val_A and Val_B in order to handle accordingly.